# SonarQube analysis loops on the same php file

Tags: php, jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I use SonarQube 6.3 with sonnar-runner 2.4 and jenkins 2.46.1

For each project building, SonarQube loops on the same php file. Why ? and How to resolve the problem ?

```
INFO  - 275/1072 files analyzed, current file: /src/Controller/LinkController.php
INFO  - 275/1072 files analyzed, current file: /src/Controller/LinkController.php
INFO  - 275/1072 files analyzed, current file: /src/Controller/LinkController.php
INFO  - 275/1072 files analyzed, current file: /src/Controller/LinkController.php
INFO  - 275/1072 files analyzed, current file: /src/Controller/LinkController.php
```

I increase memory of JVM but still the same message (i think that is not the solution)

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: It does not actually loop. It is probably stuck on the analysis of that file. How big is that file? Is it a special file like a map of key/value pairs? In any case, you can try to exclude this file to have at least your analysis done => "sonar.exclusions=**/LinkController.php"

Comment: I use Zend Framework 2. The class contains one constructor with three parameters and three small functions. I exclude this file but i have the same problem. (with an other php class). I try to comment all functions and constructor and the problem still persist.

Comment: How did you increase the JVM memory?

Comment: In the SonnarQube scanner plugin of jenkins, field : Additional arguments.

Comment: OK the problem is solved. It was not the class LinkController.php but an other big class. The information message was wrong. Thanks for your help.